# Trouble with html link tag and image

Tags: php, html, css, image, url

Got some trouble when i tried to use an url to image.

```
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Anime!</h1>
    </div>

        <?php 

            include "config/database.php";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM anime WHERE status = 'On Going' ORDER BY id";

            $query = mysql_query($sql);

            if ($query > 0){

        ?>  
    <div class="container">
            <div class="description-plate">
               <?php
                    while
                        ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $image = $row['image'];
                        $title = $row['title'];
                        $genre = $row['genre'];
                        $start = $row['start'];
                        $schedule = $row['schedule'];
                        $description = $row['description'];

                ?>
                <!--div class="caption-btm">
                    <p style="margin-left:6px; margin-top:175px;">Start Airing From:</p>
                    <h5 style="margin-left:10px;"><?php echo $start; ?></h5>
                    <p style="margin-left:6px;">Airing Schedule:</p>
                    <h5 style="margin-left:10px;"><?php echo $schedule; ?></h5>

                </div-->
                <div class="thumbnail-fluid">
                    <a href="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
                    <div id="og-plate">
                                <div><img src="admin/<?php echo $row['image'];  ?>"></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

So when i tried to call the image using php, the  tag only appear on the last image. What i'm trying to do is having the  tag on every images. Would appreciate any help, thanks :)

Comment: Seems like you have extra `<?php } ?>` right after image div.

Comment: @dfsq thats what i found

Comment: oops sorry, please check the script again. forgot to paste the full script, my bad :)

Comment: Hm you have that close bracked right in the middle of an `<a></a>` tag, even though now it makes sense that you need to have 2, that still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Elin! Hope i can give a reputation for your reply but it seems someone just reduced my rep because of this silly question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are going through the loop (not sure why you are using `while`) and each time creating

```
        <div class="thumbnail-fluid">
            <a href="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
            <div id="og-plate">
                        <div><img src="admin/<?php echo $row['image'];  ?>"></div>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

What you want to do is build up an html string on each pass appending the next image tag, something more like

...

```
$myimages = '';    
   while  // skipped details
       $myimages .=   '  <div class="thumbnail-fluid">
                <a href=". $row['image'] .  '>
                <div id="og-plate">
                            <div><img src="admin/' . $row['image'] . '></div>'

                . '</div>
                </a>
            </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its  appear last image because ORDER BY id and the condition status = 'On Going' can return one image. Your html structure should be like this.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">Anime!</h1>
</div>

<?php
include "config/database.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM anime WHERE status = 'On Going' ORDER BY id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$n = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($n > 0) {
    ?>  
    <div class="container">
        <div class="description-plate">
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $image = $row['image'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $genre = $row['genre'];
                $start = $row['start'];
                $schedule = $row['schedule'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                ?>
                <div class="thumbnail-fluid">
                    <a href="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
                        <div id="og-plate">
                            <div><img src="admin/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>"></div>                    
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

    </div>
<?php } ?>
```